# Adobe React-Spectrum TextField error using refs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, adobe

Good Day,

I'm trying to build a login page using Adobe's react-spectrum. I need to use userefs on the TextField components because I'll need it for my AuthenticationContext. Their [docs](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-spectrum/TextField.html#props) doesn't detail use for refs. I've also checked DefinitelyTyped's [page](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35572) regarding the issue but had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Code below:

```
  const LoginForm = () => {

  const emailRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>
  const passwordRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>
  .
  .
  .

      <Form isRequired necessityIndicator="label">
        <TextField
          label="email"
          placeholder="secret@agent.com"
          isRequired
          value={email}
          onChange={setEmail}
          ref={emailRef}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Password"
          placeholder="Password"
          isRequired
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={setPassword}
          ref={passwordRef}
        />

        <Button variant="cta" onPress={LogIn} marginTop="5%">
          Log In
        </Button>
      </Form>
```

Comment: Could you describe your issue please? I have used refs with react-spectrum but I'm not sure exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

first import TextFieldRef

```
import TextFieldRef from '@react-types/textfield'
```

inside your main function / hook

```
const passwordRef = React.useRef<TextFieldRef.TextFieldRef>(null)
```

in tag element

```
<TextField
    ref={passwordRef}
    />
```

on other function

```
if(passwordRef && passwordRef.current) {
    passwordRef.current.getInputElement().focus()
}
```